# Assembly syntax to distinguish two forms of near jump

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, masm

I'm assembling the same source with two different assemblers. I expect to get two identical results (modulo memory offsets, exact value of NOPs and such). Yet I've suddenly encountered the weirdest issue: there are two possible encodings of JZ:

```
74 cb
```

and

```
0F 84 cw/cd
```

The displacement, in my case, fits into one byte, and one assembler (a flavor of GAS, I think) emits the former while another (MASM) emits the latter. Since I perform some validation by matching outputs, this throws the validation off.

I have rather little control over the options of GAS, but I have complete control over MASM. Question - is there an option, a directive, or a specific command syntax to force one encoding over the other?

Comment: For reference, is this just `jz some_label`?

Comment: Sure it is. Local label, all quite vanilla.

Comment: Which version of MASM is this? If I use 6.14.8444 and enter the following code: `jz @@test` / `@@test:` I get `74 00` when I disassemble the binary.

Comment: The GNU assembler has specific options to force sizes on direct-encoded operands, either via the `.d8` / `.d32` suffixes, or else the `data8` / `data32` / `code16` prefixes. See http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dDependent.html for details.

Comment: What is the exact code and compilation commands? GAS is configured to take Intel syntax input is that it?

Comment: Thanks for attention, but the whole issue is not relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the code, except for this one instruction is the exact same when assembled, this looks like a bug in MASM. These instructions resolve to:

```
74: jz rel8
0F 84: jz rel16/32
```

So, MASM is improperly using more space for that opcode than it should. You may be able to remedy this by using a more explicit form of the instruction in MASM, like

```
jz byte my_label
```

However, if your machine code is different at all, this may be the *proper* behavior of MASM. Ensure that the **signed** word/dword argument to `jz rel16` would fit into a **signed** byte

Comment: This sounds very familiar.  I seem to recall MASM would emit the long relative version when the passes were insufficient to determine for sure it would fit in a rel8.  How many bytes out exactly is the destination?

Comment: `jz byte` doesn't look like MASM syntax. That should probably be `jz short`

Comment: The full encoding of the MASM command goes: `0F 84 7F 00 00 00`. So the EIP displacement is 7F. That might be relevant - this is exactly the threshold between byte and (d)word forms.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: The branch offset is relative to the address of the first byte following the branch instruction. So if you've got a `near` ("dword") branch with an offset of 0x7F, it means you're jumping to 133 (127+6) bytes after the _start_ of the branch instruction. For a `short` jump to be able to jump to the same place it would have to be able to encode an offset of +131, which of course it can't.

Comment: Right; but were it a short form of JZ, it would be only two bytes, and 7F would point exactly to the same address. GAS does it right.

Comment: Yeah. MASM 6.14.8444 gets it right even in the border case though (i.e. it will generate `74 7F`). I can't guarantee that it will do so for your code, however.

Comment: Mine is the one that comes with VS2005 - says it's v.8.00.50727.762.